# SQL: different aggregate values for different condition

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have such a difficult problem from my knowledge.

I need to write a sole query that perform this action:

> write a query that for the day Monday extract the sum of computer
>   sold, and for the rest of the days just the sum of Laptop.

For example I have this table

```
Day      LaptopSold DesktopSold Total
Monday      2            2        4
Tuesday     2            3        5
Monday      1            1        2
Wednesday   2            2        4
Tuesday     1            4        5
```

The result should be this:

```
Day       QtySold
Monday      6
Tuesday     3
wed         2
```

I can achieve the goal just writing two separate queries with the `Group By` for the `Day` field, but in one query for me is impossible!!!

Could you help me, please!!!
Thanks in advance
Lu

Comment: How does the `Monday` value equal six (6)?  Shouldn't it be two (2)?

Comment: @BellevueBob There is 2 lines that having Monday as day...and for monday you need to look at the total column :)

Comment: @FabienTheSolution Sheesh, I need more coffee (or glasses)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can select the additive field with a `CASE`:

```
SELECT DAY, 
       SUM(CASE DAY 
             WHEN 'MONDAY' THEN TOTAL 
             ELSE LAPTOPSOLD 
           END) AS QtySold 
FROM   TBL 
GROUP  BY DAY
```